# Django aggregation - Sum of two Sums

Tags: django, models, django-aggregation

Let's assume we have the following two models:

```
class Player(Model):
    alliance = ForeignKey("Alliance")
    points = PositiveIntegerField()

class Alliance(Model):
    points = PositiveIntegerField()
```

Every player and every alliance have a specific amount of points. Total alliance points are count `alliance.points + Sum(player_set__points)`.

What I want to do is to fetch all the alliances ordered by the amount of total points.
The problem is that I do not seem to be able to do Sum + Sum in aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You can denormalize your DB. Add a field `sum` on an `Alliance`, an update it on `post_save` and `post_delete` of `Alliance` and `Player`. So you'll have ready-to-use value and sort on it easily.

Comment: Well, prestige of the player changes very often and because of that I want to calculate the sum on the fly. It seems to be impossible, doesn't it?

Comment: Not impossible, you always can have raw sql. But much less elegant.